# How do you export from Expression Design to Silverlight XAML and retain vector relativity?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, export, blend

I am trying to export some prepared assets out of Expression Design 2 and into .XAML, with a final destination of Blend 2 for layout, but I cannot find a reliable way to keep the ability to resize those assets when they reach Blend. Taking a look at the exported final product, the XAML produced is wrapped in a Canvas (whether or not I select that option in Export) with hard-coded Left/Top attached properties and Width/Height. This means whatever size I exported the asset becomes its fixed size and I no longer have the ability to control its dimensions in Blend.

How do I export my assets and keep their dynamic resizability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a scale transform to the Canvas in Blend.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Those scale transforms eluded me because I'm used to resizing a reticle to change scale and doing that in Blend on a Canvas just changes the clipping.